# Cassandra code 10 - Unknown code 65535 for a consistency level

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I'm running 4 node cluster on Cassandra 3.11.8.
I'm testing Consistency levels, when I set local quorum, local serial or local one as the Read Consistency, I got following error:
Cassandra code 10 - Unknown code 65535 for a consistency level

The other values work fine without any error.
However I cannot find any documentation above  code. Could anyone please suggest a solution that works for me?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error previously when someone is executing batches which contains more than 64K statements which is beyond the limit.

I have to admit that I'm struggling to understand a valid use case beyond 10s of statements in a batch, let alone hundreds or thousands. If you do have very large batches, I'd like to point out that batches are not an optimisation in the same manner as they are in RDBMS.

This is however a little contrary to your description that you're setting read consistency so perhaps there's some wires crossed here. In any case, `SERIAL` and `LOCAL_SERIAL` consistencies are only valid for the read phase in the read-before-write of lightweight transactions so they're not valid for regular reads. Cheers!

**[EDIT]** If you provide a bit code that replicates the issue, I'd be happy to review it and figure out the underlying issue. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for sharing your experience. unfortunately, it doesn't seem it works for my current issue, because it is very small statement.
but your advice is so meaningful for another perspective on my tests.

If there would be further suggestion to help me to understand above error code, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Hirono the error itself is a bit generic and hides the underlying issue. Can you provide a bit of code that replicates the problem? Also, which driver + driver version are you using?

Comment: Hi Eric,
I'm so sorry for confusing you but I found it was caused by another product's defect.
Thank you for your kindly advice.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. Cheers!